# Dynamic XML node name in SQL XML

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am updating an XML column with values from columns in a temp table. I can update the table as below.

```
UPDATE  tbWorkflow 
SET     xmlData.modify('insert 
                (<FromQueueName>
                <CustomerID>{ sql:column("T.iVTollCustID") }</CustomerID>
                <Date>{ sql:variable("@CurrDateTime") }</Date>
                </FromQueueName>)                           
                as first into (/configuration)[1]'),
        vcQueue             =   'qVtoll',
        dtUpdTime           =   GETDATE()
FROM    #Trxns    T 
WHERE   T.biWorkflowID      =   tbWorkflow.biWorkflowID
```

However, I want the node name to be dynamic (from the temp table) like below. But it does not work.

```
UPDATE  tbWorkflow 
SET     xmlData.modify('insert 
                (<**{ sql:column("T.vcQueue") }**>
                <CustomerID>{ sql:column("T.iVTollCustID") }</CustomerID>
                <Date>{ sql:variable("@CurrDateTime") }</Date>
                </**{ sql:column("T.vcQueue") }**>)                         
                as first into (/configuration)[1]'),
        vcQueue             =   'qVtoll',
        dtUpdTime           =   GETDATE()
FROM    #Trxns    T 
WHERE   T.biWorkflowID      =   tbWorkflow.biWorkflowID
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For **what database** is this? MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? DB2? They all use **SQL** - but they all do things a slight bit different - knowing what **concrete database** this is for is invaluable for us to help you! Please update your **tags** accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to do this.

I added another VARCHAR column to my temp table, created the xml node as a varchar and later modified my actual xml column using this varchar column.

```
UPDATE  #Trxns
SET     xmlVarchar = '<' + vcQueue + '>
        <CustomerID>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),iVTollCustID) + '</CustomerID>
        <Date>' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(),22) + '</Date>' +
        '</' + vcQueue + '>'


UPDATE  tbWorkflow 
SET     xmlData.modify('insert 
                sql:column("xmlVarchar")
                as first into (/configuration)[1]'),
        vcQueue             =   'qVtoll',
        dtUpdTime           =   GETDATE()
FROM    #Trxns    T  
WHERE   T.biWorkflowID      =   tbWorkflow.biWorkflowID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use a subquery to select a string you need and then insert it into XML.
For example, in subquery get a `<YourTag><CustomerID>123</CustomerID><Date>15.10.2012</Date></YourTag>` and then you can simply insert it in XML